# How to disable timestamp value of update_at?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

Here is the error:

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1504595835' for column 'updated_at' at row 1
The SQL being executed was: UPDATE `user` SET `password_reset_token`='zDPxEMdJ2EaaCf2VsI_Uf9QNf0q2MKcn_1504595835', `updated_at`='1504595835' WHERE `id`=19
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 22007
    [1] => 1292
    [2] => Incorrect datetime value: '1504595835' for column 'updated_at' at row 1
)
```

I don't know where that timestamp is getting assigned for the updated_at field.

I tried to set value for updated_at as date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), but still, there is no luck.

I tried to set the behaviour also, but still no luck.

Can anyone help with sort this problem?

Comment: What's your default mySQL column type for  `updated_at`

Comment: Its timestamp..

Comment: In your model, find method  "public function behaviors(){}" There is "TimestampBehavior", check its manual, set value here.

Answer (score 0):

you have declared your column "updated_at" and "created_at" wrong. you have to change it to

```
int(11)
```

as described in [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html)

Comment: but I am not doing anything, its Yii handling everything by its own, I just call $user->save() and not passing any value for updated_at

Comment: i've updated my answer to match your question better

Comment: then it will store time stamp right? but I want to store current date and time

Comment: a timestamp IS the current date and time - just use 
    
    `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(updated_at) FROM user`

Comment: Hello mate! When I am trying to save user data, updated_at is getting assigned to it from somewhere and then I am getting that error.

Comment: just change the column to `int(11)` - and when you want to display it as datetime use `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(updated_at) FROM user`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153726/discussion-between-halko-sajtarevic-and-rahul-meshram).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save updated_at in number format change your data type to int(11)

or if you want to save in datetime format use

```
$model->updated_at = date_format(date_create(), 'Y:m:d: H:i:s')
```

and change your datatype to datetime

Answer (score 0):

first change dataType to datetime in table.

crate ActiveRecord.php in common\components

```
<?php
namespace common\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Exception;

/**
 * Class ActiveRecord
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 * @package common\components
 */
class ActiveRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

    public function beforeSave($v){
        if($this->isNewRecord) {
            try {
                $this->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            } catch (Exception $e) {}
        }

        try {
            $this->updated_at=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        } catch (Exception $e) {}
        return parent::beforeSave($v);
    }


}
```

check **beforeSave** function
extent ActiveRecord from  common\components\ActiveRecord
eg.

```
<?php
namespace common\models;
use common\components\ActiveRecord;
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First think created_at and updated_at is managed by behaviour in common/models/User model and your database table column data type should be "BIGINT" for saving those records.

Another way to save updated_at in "yyyy/mm/dd h:i:s" format you need to remove Use model behaviour function and save these records manually after changing the database table column datatype